# Долгая загрузка фрагмента

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragment, backstack

Имеется фрагмент, куда загружается тяжелая информация (загрузка длится несколько секунд), загрузка происходит в методе `onCreateView`. Из этого фрагмента имеется возможность перейти к другому фрагменту (при переходе к нему он добавляется в backstack). При нажатии кнопки "назад" происходит переход к первому фрагменту и опять же приходится долго ждать, пока он загрузится. Как можно ускорить этот процесс? Данные первого фрагмента из второго изменить нельзя, так что необходимости заново загружать первый фрагмент нет.

Данные берутся из БД

Comment: делайте в фоне тяжелые операции, тем самим разгрузите основной поток и фрагмент будет раньше показан

Comment: @AndriyMartsinkevych а можно ли как-то предотвратить повторную загрузку фрагмента при возвращении назад без танцев с бубном?

Comment: он не будет грузится повторно. будет только повторно вызван метод onCreateView

Comment: загрузка данных из БД не должна занимать столько времени (если речь не идет о миллионах записей, так например 10 000 записей загружаются менее секунды) поэтому нужно оптимизировать работу с БД, запросы. Для загрузки использовать CursorLoader.

Comment: @pavlofff у меня используется запрос, в котором 2 подзапроса, в одном из которых есть собственный подзапрос, а также сортировка по двум критериям в основном запросе

Answer (score 0):

Сохраните данные в базу, а в методе onCreateView добавьте проверку, загружены ли данные и если загружены, то берите их не из сети а из базы. Либо храните данные в памяти, к примеру в активити, но тогда они пропадут при смене конфигурации. Также данные можно хранить в памяти, к примеру в синглтоне (не лучшая практика, но работает). Советую обратить внимание на Clean Architecture или MV* архитектуру, когда разберетесь, такие вопросы не будут возникать.

Comment: не уточнил, что данные и так берутся из БД

Comment: ну тогда вариант с синглтоном подходит. проверяете, есть ли в нем данные, показываете во фрагменте если есть, если нет, грузите, сохраняете в синглтон и показываете. Если интересен правильный дизайн, сделайте локальный синглтон с помощью инъекции зависимостей. Также можно хранить данные в поле класса Application.